# FourierTransform and InverseFourierTransform are not inverses when using non-default FourierParameters

Tags: bugs, fourier-analysis, inverse

`FourierTransform` and `InverseFourierTransform` are inverses of each other when using the default `FourierParameters`:

> In: `FourierTransform[1/t, t, ω]`
>
> Out: `I Sqrt[π/2] Sign[ω]`
>
> In: `InverseFourierTransform[I Sqrt[π/2] Sign[ω], ω, t]`
>
> Out: `1/t`

But if we use the non-default `FourierParameters -> {1,1}`, then it no longer works right:

> In: `FourierTransform[1/t, t, ω, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]`
>
> Out: `I π Sign[ω]`
>
> In: `InverseFourierTransform[I π Sign[ω], ω, t, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]`
>
> Out: `1/t + I π DiracDelta[t] - 2 I π^2 DiracDelta[t]`

Where are the extra terms `I π DiracDelta[t] - 2 I π^2 DiracDelta[t]` coming from in the last expression?

Comment: In the `InverseFourierTransform` add the option `Assumptions -> t > 0`

Comment: @BobHanlon Why? I want to consider general values of $t$.

Comment: `FourierTransform[1/t, t, \[Omega]]` is not a usual Fourier transform since `1/t` is not absolutely integrable over $\mathbb R$. This transform is defined in a certain complicated way, not through an improper integral. As far as I understand it, the `FourierParameters` option is applicable for usual Fourier transforms only.

Comment: Documentation states "Integral transforms can produce results that involve "generalized functions""

Comment: Then use `Assumptions -> t != 0` that is no more restrictive than the presence of the term `1/t`

Answer (score 7):

Mathematica doesn't handle `Sign[]` correctly. With the substitution `Sign[omega]->2 HeavisideTheta[omega]-1` the inverse transformation evaluates correctly to

```
InverseFourierTransform[I \[Pi] (2 HeavisideTheta[\[Omega] ] - 1), \[Omega],t,FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
(*1/t*)
```

Comment: Should I report this to Wolfram as a bug?

Comment: @tparker Yes you should do it!